# Escape a string in SQL Server so that it is safe to use in LIKE expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-like

How do I escape a string in SQL Server's stored procedure so that it is safe to use in `LIKE` expression.

Suppose I have an `NVARCHAR` variable like so:

```
declare @myString NVARCHAR(100);
```

And I want to use it in a `LIKE` expression:

```
... WHERE ... LIKE '%' + @myString + '%';
```

How do I escape the string (more specifically, characters that are meaningful to `LIKE` pattern matching, e.g. `%` or `?`) in T-SQL, so that it is safe to use in this manner?

For example, given:

```
@myString = 'aa%bb'
```

I want:

```
WHERE ... LIKE '%' + @somehowEscapedMyString + '%'
```

to match `'aa%bb'`, `'caa%bbc'` but not `'aaxbb'` or `'caaxbb'`.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

To escape special characters in a LIKE expression you prefix them with an escape character. You get to choose which escape char to use with the ESCAPE keyword. ([MSDN Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx))

For example this escapes the % symbol, using \ as the escape char:

```
select * from table where myfield like '%15\% off%' ESCAPE '\'
```

If you don't know what characters will be in your string, and you don't want to treat them as wildcards, you can prefix all wildcard characters with an escape char, eg:

```
set @myString = replace( 
                replace( 
                replace( 
                replace( @myString
                ,    '\', '\\' )
                ,    '%', '\%' )
                ,    '_', '\_' )
                ,    '[', '\[' )
```

(Note that you have to escape your escape char too, and make sure that's the inner `replace` so you don't escape the ones added from the other `replace` statements). Then you can use something like this:

```
select * from table where myfield like '%' + @myString + '%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Also remember to allocate more space for your @myString variable as it will become longer with the string replacement.

Comment: Currently I am using approach mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861004/escaping-the-escape-character-does-not-work-sql-like-operator Do you see any shortcomings with that code?

Comment: @Lijo, that's fine. That answer does the escaping in C# whereas the above answer does it in SQL as it's not C#-specific. Either way the result is the same: escape any special chars in your search string and use the ESCAPE keyword in your LIKE  statement.

Comment: I think you also need to escape a single quote (replacing it with two single quotes, not with `\'`).

Comment: @TedHopp - no, you don't need to escape `'` for the purposes of LIKE, because it's not a special character for LIKE. For example this works fine: `declare @s nvarchar(max); set @s = '%''%';
with a_cte as ( select 'I''m adam' as aColumn )
select * from a_cte where aColumn like @s;`

Comment: @TedHopp - what you're probably referring to is just the need to use two `'` in order to define a single quote in a string constant. Yes you need to do that, but the resulting string value only has a single quote: the escaping is done just to get the single quote into the string variable when declaring it as a constant value. You could select the `'` from somewhere and wouldn't need to escape it.

Comment: ...In the case of LIKE special chars the string value actually contains the escape character. So if you `print @myString` from my answer you'll see values like `15\% off` but if you `print @s` from my previous comment it will just look like `%'%`, i.e. just a single quote.

Answer (score 19):

Had a similar problem (using NHibernate, so the ESCAPE keyword would have been very difficult) and solved it using the bracket characters. So your sample would become

```
WHERE ... LIKE '%aa[%]bb%'
```

If you need proof:

```
create table test (field nvarchar(100))
go
insert test values ('abcdef%hijklm')
insert test values ('abcdefghijklm')
go
select * from test where field like 'abcdef[%]hijklm'
go
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Doesn't rely on escape and works for all strings.

Comment: I think this is the simplest and so closest to what the asker was looking for. Not to say that ESCAPE is not as useful in some cases.

Comment: Still there’s no explanation of how to reliably get a list of characters which need escaping or how to take an arbitrary string and properly escape it.

Answer (score 15):

Rather than escaping **all** characters in a string that have particular significance in the pattern syntax given that you are using a leading wildcard in the pattern it is quicker and easier just to do.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(@myString , YourColumn) > 0
```

In cases where you are not using a leading wildcard the approach above should be avoided however as it cannot use an index on `YourColumn`.

Additionally in cases where the optimum execution plan will vary according to the number of matching rows the estimates may be better when using `LIKE` with the square bracket escaping syntax when compared to [both `CHARINDEX`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/46917/3690) and [the `ESCAPE` keyword](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47206/3690).

Comment: Excellent! But what if there was no leading wild card?

Comment: @Colin - If there was no leading wildcard and the aim was to escape **all** wild card characters elsewhere in the string then you could just use `=` instead. The escaping special characters answers could still be useful for a query looking for values starting with a particular value though as `LIKE` can use an index in that case but `CHARINDEX` can't.

Answer (score 4):

You specify the escape character.   Documentation here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: I was wishing for something that already nows what needs to be escaped in a  LIKE expression.

Comment: The answer suggested you specify your own escape character so "meaningful " characters will not be meaningful anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to look for strings that include an escape character? For instance you want this:

```
select * from table where myfield like '%10%%'.
```

Where you want to search for all fields with 10%? If that is the case then you may use the ESCAPE clause to specify an escape character and escape the wildcard character.

```
select * from table where myfield like '%10!%%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Comment: I added an example of what I want to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative escaping syntax:

> [LIKE Wildcard Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-sql-escape-sequences?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> The JDBC driver supports the **{escape 'escape character'}** syntax for using LIKE clause wildcards as literals.

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE col LIKE 'a\_c' {escape '\'};
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e4080bf5917b482e809013444f1fc40b)**