# Search-Filtering GridView control results in no records found

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, search, ado.net

I'm trying to filter-search the data from a `GridView` control which is bound to a SQL data connection but i'm not having any success. Whenever I try to search for something, it results in no records found. Here is my main searching code:

```
    public void FilterGridView(string column, string terms) //SELECT * FROM [Table_1] WHERE [First Name] LIKE '%valuetosearchfor%' is the format to use here
    {
        DataTable filterTable = new DataTable(); //create a datatable to hold the data while we retrieve it
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TAMUWINPART\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=phpMyWorkers;Integrated Security=True"); //connect to SQL
        try
        {
            connection.Open(); //open the connection

            string filterStatement = "SELECT * FROM [Table_1] WHERE @column LIKE '%@terms%'"; //select all from table_1 with the correct column name / terms

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(filterStatement, connection); //make a sql command 
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //make it an average joe sql text command

            //define the @ sql variables
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", column);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terms",  terms);

            SqlDataAdapter filterAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd); //make a data adapter to get all the data from the command and put it into the data table

            filterAdapter.Fill(filterTable);  //fill the data table with the data from the SQL connection

            if(filterTable.Rows.Count > 0)  //if records were found relating to the terms
            {
                //if records WERE found
                workersView.DataSource = filterTable; //set the data source to this instead
                workersView.DataBind(); //refresh the data
            }
            else
            {
                //no records were found in this case, do not be an inneficient guy who will refresh the gridview for no reason
                FilterSearchTerms.Text = "0 Records Found!"; //notify the user that he/she won't get anything
            }
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex) //if the thing just decides that it doesn't want to work today
        {
            string msg = "myWorkers had a problem fetching the data : ";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close(); //close the connection
        }
    }

    public void FilterSearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //when someone clicks the button to filtersearch the gridviews
    {
        string column = FilterSearchDropdown.SelectedValue.ToString(); //get the column that the user wants to filter by and make sure it's a string
        string terms = FilterSearchTerms.Text;    //get the terms to search by - verified string for sure

        FilterGridView(column, terms);
    }

    public void FilterRemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //when someone decides to remove the filter
    {
        BindGridView(); //refresh the gridview based on all of the data
        FilterSearchTerms.Text = ""; //remove the text from the filter search terms box
    }
```

Here is a picture of what the layout looks like.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/FsGXgKz.png]

Even if I search for real data it results  in this being called

```
        else
        {
            //no records were found in this case, do not be an inneficient guy who will refresh the gridview for no reason
            FilterSearchTerms.Text = "0 Records Found!"; //notify the user that he/she won't get anything
        }
```

meaning that the datatable's row count is 0...

Does anyone know why? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line :

```
 string column = FilterSearchDropdown.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

with this:

```
 string column = FilterSearchDropdown.SelectedText;
```

Also, you need correct your command string  and command  parameters as Emmad Kareem suggested in other answer. Your string and parameter should be like below:

```
  string filterStatement = "SELECT * FROM [Table_1] WHERE [{0}] LIKE @terms"; //select all from table_1 with the correct column name / terms
  filterStatement = string.Format(filterStatement, column);
  ....      ....      ....      ....      ....      ....  

 // sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", column );
  sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terms", "%" + terms + "%");
```

Comment: I got it working with FilterSearchDropdown.SelectedItem.Text... thanks! I didn't know that this would work but it does. I would upvote you but sadly I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your SQL LIKE code is incorrect. Take a look at how to use like with SQL parameter in this question:[how-to-get-like-clause-to-work-in-ado-net-and-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589283/how-to-get-like-clause-to-work-in-ado-net-and-sql-server). It would also help to display the final sql command text that gets sent to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to replace this query:

```
string filterStatement = "SELECT * FROM [Table_1] WHERE @column LIKE '%"+terms+"%'";
```

And you should be able to find your data.

Comment: That is a solution but usually embedding unfiltered input into your query is not a nice thing to do (because of potential SQL injection). Better use a parameter that can be cleaned (look at the accepted answer).