# EF Sql Query parameters not returning results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a working query that returns 140 rows from the db:

```
string tag = "New York";

string sql = "select   " +
"    T.Id       TagId, " +
"    PM.Id      MachineId, " +
$"    '{tag}'     TagSiteName, " +
"    T.Name     TagCpeMachineLine, " +
"    PM.Plant, " +
"    PM.Line, " +
"    PM.Type " +
"from Tags T " +
"inner join PaperMachines PM " +
"    ON PM.Id = T.PaperMachineId " +
$"WHERE T.Name LIKE ( '{tag}' ) ";

var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<TagsMachines>(sql);
```

When I try to parameterize it, I get 'Enumeration yielded no results' from the result.

```
string tag = "New York";

string sql = "select   " +
"    T.Id       TagId, " +
"    PM.Id      MachineId, " +
"    '@tag'     TagSiteName, " +
"    T.Name     TagCpeMachineLine, " +
"    PM.Plant, " +
"    PM.Line, " +
"    PM.Type " +
"from Tags T " +
"inner join PaperMachines PM " +
"    ON PM.Id = T.PaperMachineId " +
"WHERE T.Name LIKE ( '@tag' ) ";

var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<TagsMachines>(sql, new SqlParameter("@tag", tag));
```

I'm not sure what's going on here.  Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the quotes around all instances of the parameter. It should just be `@tag`, never `'@tag'` unless you want the verbatim string value `'@tag'` used/returned.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **@tag** from top of your Query and at the bottom of your Query make it 
`T.Name = @tag  or T.Name like ('%' + @tag +'%')` if you want like contains.
Finally at the end of the result line add `a .FirstOrDefault().`

Comment: I figured it likely had to do with the single quotes.  I did remove them around the tag parameter, but the T.Name like ('%' + @tag +'%') did not work.  I looked at another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589283/how-to-get-like-clause-to-work-in-ado-net-and-sql-server   and added the wildcard % in the actual sql parameter value: var result2 = db.Database.SqlQuery<TagsMachines>(sql2, new SqlParameter("@tag", $"{tag}%")).ToList();

Comment: Yeah should have been double quotes instead of single like "%" + @tag + "%"  or you could instead omit the entire SqlParameter off and instead Use a filter after your query something like .Where(i=>TagSiteName.Contains(tag)).ToList()  now of course this would most likely have the performance hit  of returning too much to be filtered afterwards