# Restructured SQL Query but it does not display elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a dropdown list `ddlProjecsFilter` that I populate with the names of all projects in my database.

On page load, I show this dropdown list and when a person selects a Name, they get all the information regarding that Project Name. However, I have two extra filters based on character input (Funder, Type).

When writing the query like this, the dropdown list has no elements in it, yet the two other filters work.

```
  protected void nameFilter()
    {
        string queryDefault = "SELECT NULL AS [Value], 'All' AS [Text], '0' AS [OrderNo] UNION ALL ";
        string queryBase = "SELECT [NameId] AS [Value], [Type] AS [Text], '1' AS [OrderNo] FROM [tblProjects] ";
        string queryWhere = " WHERE NameId IS NOT NULL ";
        string queryOrder = " ORDER BY [OrderNo], [Text]";


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTypeFilter.Text))
        {
            queryWhere +=" AND [Funder] LIKE @Funder";
            queryWhere += " AND [Type] LIKE @Type";
        }

        sdsProjects.SelectCommand = queryDefault + queryBase + queryWhere + queryOrder;
        sdsProjects.SelectParameters.Add("@Funder", txtFunderFilter.Text);
        sdsProjects.SelectParameters.Add("@Type", txtTypeFilter.Text);

        ddlProjectsFilter.DataBind();
    }
```

If I however do it like this, everything works as intended. However, this is not best practice.

```
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTypeFilter.Text))
        {
            queryWhere += string.Format(" AND [Funder] LIKE'%{0}%'", txtFunderFilter.Text);
            queryWhere += string.Format(" AND [Type] LIKE'%{0}%'", txtTypeFilter.Text);
        }
```

Can anyone point out the issue with the first snippet?

Definitions:

```
 <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsProjects" ID="ddlProjectsFilter"
                                            AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value"
                                            CssClass="form-control local-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProjectsFilter_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                        </asp:DropDownList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsProjectsFilter" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseLive %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTypeFilter" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtTypeFilter_TextChanged"
                                            CssClass="form-control local-control TypeFilter"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFunderFilter" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtFunderFilter_TextChanged"
                                            CssClass="form-control local-control FunderFilter"></asp:TextBox></td>...
```

Comment: hmm.. they aren't equivalent.. if the second query was `LIKE '{0}'` (without wildcards) they would be.  so the issue with the first query is probably that it needs a wildcard.  I'm not sure if the `.Text`, or parameter value would include that wildcard though

Comment: My idea was to stray away from using %s. What needs to be changed on the first code in that case to make it equivalent to the second snippet?

Comment: provide an example of `txtFunderFilter.Text` and `txtTypeFilter.Text`, also..  what is the schema of `Funder` and `Type` fields? it's possible you have trailing whitespace going on

Comment: Like clause without wild cards will not work.

Comment: I added more definitions. Both Funder and Type are strings / nvarchar(255). How would you suggest I change the query to not use wildcards?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of SqlParameter in SQL LIKE clause not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665129/use-of-sqlparameter-in-sql-like-clause-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a good setup. However, you should "pair up" the text box test with each time you wish to add an optional parameter.

So, with this setup you can have 1 or 5 optional filters.

And because you want a like, see the code below:

So, I suggest this:

```
        SqlDataSource sdsProjects = new SqlDataSource();

        string queryDefault = "SELECT NULL AS [Value], 'All' AS [Text], '0' AS [OrderNo] UNION ALL ";
        string queryBase = "SELECT [NameId] AS [Value], [Type] AS [Text], '1' AS [OrderNo] FROM [tblProjects] ";
        string queryWhere = " WHERE NameId IS NOT NULL ";
        string queryOrder = " ORDER BY [OrderNo], [Text]";


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTypeFilter.Text))
        {
            queryWhere += " AND ([Type] LIKE '%' + @Type + '%') ";
            sdsProjects.SelectParameters.Add("@Type",DbType.String, txtTypeFilter.Text);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFunderFilter.Text))
        {
            queryWhere += " AND ([Funder] LIKE '%' + @Funder + '%') ";
            sdsProjects.SelectParameters.Add("@Funder",DbType.String, txtFunderFilter.Text);
        }

        sdsProjects.SelectCommand = queryDefault + queryBase + queryWhere + queryOrder;
```