# Postgresql query in ASP.NET C# using like operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

This code works

```
public void select()
{
    string str = "SELECT * FROM gazettes g WHERE g.title LIKE '%"+ hidden_key.Value +"%' OR serial LIKE '%"+ hidden_key.Value +"%'"; /*'%' || @title || '%'*/
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = str;
    GV_Gazette.DataBind();
}
```

but I want it to work in this as well but it returns an empty value. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void select()
{
    string str = "SELECT * FROM gazettes g WHERE g.title LIKE @title OR serial LIKE @title";/*'%' || @title || '%'*/
    cmd.CommandText = str;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", "%" + hidden_key.Value + "%");    
    dt = c.PopulateData(cmd);
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = dt.ToString();
    GV_Gazette.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Use `ILIKE` in PGSQL.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", hidden_key.Value);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665129/use-of-sqlparameter-in-sql-like-clause-not-working

Comment: @HirenPatel it doesn't work

Comment: Can you please share data set?

Comment: Please also share expected output.

Comment: public DataTable PopulateData(NpgsqlCommand command){        
 dt = new DataTable();
 command.Connection = conn;
 command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 conn.Open();
 NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
 da.SelectCommand = command;
 da.Fill(dt);
 return dt;}

@HirenPatel

Comment: @LollyMolly I think it should be `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = str;`