# Is it possible to use WHERE IN along with LIKE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

If I have to search for some data I  can use wildcards and use a simple query -

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 LIKE '%test_string%'
```

And, if I have to look through many values I can use -

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 IN (Select col from AnotherTable)
```

But, is it possible to use both together. That is, the query doesn't just perform a WHERE IN but also perform something similar to WHERE LIKE? A query that just doesn't look through a set of values but search using wildcards through a set of values.

If this isn't clear I can give an example. Let me know. Thanks.

Example -

lets consider -

AnotherTable -

```
  id  | Col
------|------
  1   |  one
  2   |  two
  3   |  three
```

Table -

```
Col   | Col1
------|------
 aa   |  one
 bb   |  two
 cc   |  three
 dd   |  four
 ee   |  one_two
 bb   |  three_two
```

Now, if I can use

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 IN (Select col from AnotherTable)
```

This gives me -

```
Col   | Col1
------|------
 aa   |  one
 bb   |  two
 cc   |  three
```

But what if I need -

```
Col   | Col1
------|------
 aa   |  one
 bb   |  two
 cc   |  three
 ee   |  one_two
 bb   |  three_two
```

I guess this should help you understand what I mean by using WHERE IN and LIKE together

Comment: added example.. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE A
   INNER JOIN AnotherTable B on
     A.COL1 = B.col
WHERE COL1 LIKE '%test_string%'
```

Based on the example code provided, give this a try. The final select statement presents the data as you have requested.

```
create table #AnotherTable
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null primary key,
    Col varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO #AnotherTable(col) values('one')
INSERT INTO #AnotherTable(col) values('two')
INSERT INTO #AnotherTable(col) values('three')

create table #Table
(
    Col varchar(100),
    Col1 varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO #Table(Col,Col1) values('aa','one')
INSERT INTO #Table(Col,Col1) values('bb','two')
INSERT INTO #Table(Col,Col1) values('cc','three')
INSERT INTO #Table(Col,Col1) values('dd','four')
INSERT INTO #Table(Col,Col1) values('ee','one_two')
INSERT INTO #Table(Col,Col1) values('ff','three_two')

SELECT * FROM #AnotherTable
SELECT * FROM #Table

SELECT * FROM #Table WHERE COL1 IN(Select col from #AnotherTable)


SELECT distinct A.*
FROM #Table A
    INNER JOIN  #AnotherTable B on
        A.col1 LIKE '%'+B.Col+'%'

DROP TABLE #Table
DROP TABLE #AnotherTable
```

Comment: he wants to be able to do: WHERE COL1 LIKE (SELECT COL FROM OTHER TABLE)

Comment: added an example to my question.

Comment: @Pavanred: Added a walk-through based on your example.

Comment: hmm Interesting.. Thanks, I will try this out.

Comment: Watch put for escaping the values from B.Col. If B.Col = '%', then the like will be A.col1 LIKE '%%%', so all of the values will match. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use the keyword AND:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 IN (Select col from AnotherTable) AND COL1 LIKE '%test_string%'
```

But in this case, you are probably better off using JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT TABLE.* FROM TABLE JOIN AnotherTable on TABLE.COL1 = AnotherTable.col WHERE TABLE.COL1 LIKE '%test_string'
```

Comment: he wants to be able to do: WHERE COL1 LIKE (SELECT COL FROM OTHER TABLE)

Comment: added an example to my question.

Comment: @Pavanred: Thanks for the example.  You will need to write a program (possibly a stored proc) that reads the values from AnotherTable and builds a SQL query containing several LIKE clauses (separated by the keyword OR) that can be executed against TABLE

Answer (score 1):

no because each element in the LIKE clause needs the wildcard and there's not a way to do that with the IN clause

Answer (score 1):

The pattern matching operators are:

1. `IN`, against a list of values,
2. `LIKE`, against a pattern,
3. [`REGEXP`/`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) against a regular expression (which includes both wildcards and alternatives, and is thus closest to "using wildcards through a set of valuws", e.g. `(ab)+a|(ba)+b` will match all strings aba...ba or bab...ab),
4. [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to get the index of a string in a set (which is represented as a comma separated string),
5. [`SOUNDS LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like) to compare strings based on how they're pronounced and
6. [`MATCH ... AGAINST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) for full-text matching.

That's about it for string matching, though there are other [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html).

For the example, you could try joining on `Table.Col1 LIKE CONCAT(AnotherTable.Col, '%')`, though performance will probably be dreadful (assuming it works).

Answer (score 1):

Try a cross join, so that you can compare every row in AnotherTable to every row in Table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Col, t.Col1
FROM AnotherTable at
CROSS JOIN Table t 
WHERE t.col1 LIKE ('%' + at.col + '%')
```

To make it safe, you'll need to escape wildcards in at.col. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression) for that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you want the rows from "Table" when "Table.Col1" is IN "AnotherTable.Col" and you also want the rows when Col1 IS LIKE '%some_string%'.

If so you want something like:

```
SELECT 
    t.* 
FROM 
    [Table] t 
LEFT JOIN 
    [AnotherTable] at ON t.Col1 = at.Col 
WHERE (at.Col IS NOT NULL
    OR t.Col1 LIKE '%some_string%')
```

Comment: I think you mean "at.Col IS NOT NULL *AND*..." The concept of this answer is correct. I suspect SQL Server will automatically ignore nulls and not try to process them with the LIKE function.

Comment: Actually I mean it as is using OR (similar to the answer by Catalin below but different syntax). I am reading the question as wanting the rows from "Table" when Table.Col1 is in AnotherTable.Col and also those rows where Table.Col1 is LIKE %some_string%.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
   COL1 IN (Select col from AnotherTable) 
   AND COL1 LIKE '%test_string%'
```

Comment: added an example to my qeustion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking about something like EXISTS?

> SELECT * FROM TABLE t WHERE EXISTS (Select col from AnotherTable t2 where t2.col = t.col like '%test_string%' )

Comment: added an example to question for more clarity

Comment: Thanks for the example. I would have to second the oppinion of Jeff and Leslie. You would have to create a stored procedure for this, and the performance there would not be good. I would say that you need to reconsider this approach.