# Does ADO.NET sanitize wildcards out of string SqlParameters?

Tags: .net, sql, ado.net, parameters

Does ADO.NET sanitize wildcards (i.e. "%" or "_") in string-type SqlParameters? Furthermore, does it need to? I've tried Googling for this, but it's hard to find exactly what I want to know.

For example, suppose I have a parameterized query:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE @prefix";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("prefix", User.UserName);
//etc...
```

But the user somehow manages to get himself a username like `%`. His idea is that he'll see all users, not just the ones he was supposed to see. Will this work, or would the `%` get a) escaped when the value is parameterized, or b) evaluated as a literal `%` by the SQL server?

Note that I realize the above would be a really lousy design. It's just a made-up example.

---

**Edit:** I've confirmed by testing that option b) doesn't happen.

```
declare @prefix as varchar(10);
set @prefix = '%';
select * from MyTable where MyField like @prefix;
--returns everything
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape it yourself, this would do it:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE (@prefix + '%') ESCAPE '~'";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("prefix", User.UserName.Replace("~", "~~").Replace("%", "~%"));
```

Comment: I like the `escape` clause. Didn't know you could do that, so I've learned something new. Wouldn't that replacement string have to be `"~%"`, though? And I think you'd need `Replace("~", "~~")` before that, right?

Comment: Consider data with single quotes and search also having `single quote`. Does this solution work? Then what about data with two consecutive single quotes?

Comment: @Lijo You escape single quote with another single quote

Answer (score 2):

No! There is nothing to sanitize, it is *valid* value. It is your problem that you put it into `LIKE` statement. ADO.net prevents `'` and other chars that can cause injection.

Comment: Well, it doesn't PREVENT a single quote, or any other character, but it makes sure all the characters will be interpreted as part of the parameter value, not as a metacharacter used to delimit the value. If you want to, you can think of it as replacing single quotes with two occurances, but actually if you're using the SqlProviders it will use a native protocol to talk to MSSQL and won't just send strings to parse them again at the server!

Comment: @TheDag first time I hear that it doesn't send the strings. Any details on that one?