# Query to find columns that end with percent symbol %

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, sql-like

What T-SQL query I should use to find out all rows that have column1 ending with `%`? I am using SQL SERVER 2000. Sample data in column1:

```
column1
-------
100px
100%  <- THIS ROW
200px
200%  <- THIS ROW
300px
300%  <- THIS ROW
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TMP TABLE(COL VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @TMP VALUES ('100%')
INSERT INTO @TMP VALUES ('100px')

SELECT * FROM @TMP WHERE COL LIKE '%[%]'
```

Please check out question [Escape a string in SQL Server so that it is safe to use in LIKE expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression) for more examples of escaping special characters.

The official documentation is in the [MSDN article for the LIKE operator (SQL Server 2000)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232(v=sql.80).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column1 LIKE '%[%]'
```