# Manually sanitize SQL parameters

Tags: sql, ado.net, ddl

I would like to run a script like:

```
CREATE LOGIN [me] WITH PASSWORD = @0
```

and run it like:

```
var createUserCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
createUserCommand.CommandText = script;
createUserCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", passwordDecrypted);
```

However, this throws:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '@0'.

From what I read online (nowhere official, just from SO answers/comments) it is not possible to use SQL parameters with DDL statements. Link to official docs for this are welcome!

OK. I do need this parametrized. As I see it, there are 2 options:

- I manually sanitize (`.Replace("'", "''"`) => how can I do this best?
- I call into .NET to sanitize for me. However I assume this is not sanitized within ADO.NET, but just past to SQL Server, and sanitized there...

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to escape is the single `'` to 2 x `'`

```
commandText = string.Format("CREATE LOGIN [me] WITH PASSWORD = '{0}'", pass.Replace("'", "''"));
```

An alternative would be to create a stored procedure with a password parameter and use it to build a `CREATE LOGIN` string which you then `sp_executeSQL`.

Comment: Thanks, that's easy! Can you point to more documentation that this is enough?

Comment: I can't find any definitive documentation but its mentioned here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163523.aspx / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476252/characters-that-must-be-escaped-in-tsql

Comment: According to the MSDN link, wouldn't using QUOTENAME (SQL) be a better option than using String.Replace() (.NET)

Comment: It wont wont with you DML (it wont like `PASSWORD = function(..)` and you have the password as a string literal so you would end up trying to do `QUOTENAME('XXX'YYY', '''')` which is invalid