# Multiple conditions on a particular column in a sql query

Tags: sql, special-characters, sql-like

Example Table (Person_data)

```html
Name   |   Area      |   Id
=============================== 
Jack   | A_102       |  102   
Roy    | Abc-34      |  109   
tom    | ABC6778     |  107    
Aly    | hj23        |  122   
Saly   | dsfds       |  342
```

I need a query such that it returns all the rows where Area column doesn't contain `_` or `-` or `Abc` or `ABC`.

My query

```html
Select * from Person_data 
where area not like '%-%' 
or area not like '%_%' 
or area not like '%Abc%' 
or area not like '%ABC%';
```

Comment: Which rows in your sample data should your output actually contain?

Comment: @Tim I needed a count of such entries with the mentioned condition.
Its done Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> returns all the rows where Area column doesn't contain '_' or '-' or
>   'Abc' or 'ABC'

You need to combine these search conditions with `AND`'s, but the problem is the `_` which is a a reserved wildcard in the `LIKE` predicate. You have to escape it in the `LIKE` predicate using `[]` or you can determine any escape character to use to escape it using the  `ESCAPE` keyword something like `LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'`, therefore it will treated like a literal, and it is the standard way to that like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PersonData
WHERE area NOT LIKE '%-%'
AND area NOT LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'
AND area NOT LIKE '%Abc%' 
AND area NOT LIKE '%ABC%';
```

### [Here is a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93e9c/5)

Comment: @Mahmoud - quick SQL Fiddle tip - when OP provides sample data in some kind of regular format (such as this one) you can copy and paste that data into SQL Fiddle's "Text to DDL" tool to quickly build a database table using that data.  For example, in this case, here's what it would have produced: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8480a/1  (Should make for answering these questions less tedious).  Cheers!

Comment: @JakeFeasel - First of all, Thank you very very much for SQL Fiddle, I always wish to thank you for it. Secondly thanks for the tip. Great work.

Comment: It's my pleasure - keep up the good work helping people with their database problems!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM PersonData
WHERE area NOT LIKE '%-%'
    AND area NOT LIKE '%[_]%' -- brackets for special character matching
    AND area NOT LIKE '%Abc%' 
    AND area NOT LIKE '%ABC%';
```

As others have mentioned, you probably want `AND` operators rather than `OR` operators since your current query looks like it would probably return anything that's non-null.

Also, you must [escape or bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757) the matching of a literal underscore `_` as that is a special [wildcard character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) in SQL Server (`NOT LIKE '%_%'` is semantically identical to `LIKE ''`).

Another interesting thing here is the use of both `Abc` and `ABC`, which is only necessary if you need [case-sensitivity](http://www.abstraction.net/ViewArticle.aspx?articleID=72).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really ask a question, but I think you want your "ORs" to be "ANDs".

Answer (score 0):

Replace OR with AND. Now it gets all the rows which don't contain at least one of the symbols.

Comment: is there an easier way to do the same thing

Comment: I don't see what can be easier than replacing OR with AND. Also you can do `LOWER(area) NOT LIKE '%abc%'` instead of two cases, but I think that's it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `AND` conditions for your WHERE clause instead of OR conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Person_data` 
WHERE `area` NOT LIKE '%-%' 
AND `area` NOT LIKE '%_%' 
AND `area` NOT LIKE '%Abc%' 
AND `area` NOT LIKE '%ABC%';
```