# Finding records where field contains %

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a text field that contains a percentage sign.  I need 3 chars from the left of that percentage sign...but since the percentage sign is a wildcard I'm having some issues.

```
charindex(field,'%') from...
```

That is how I'd normally go about this as part of a substring function, but since % is a wildcard, the charindex returns 0 for any non null record.  Any idea's on how I specify this to the char '%' instead of the % wildcard?

Tried to search this one on the forums, but just ended up sifting through unrelated questions.

Comment: So many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=like+escape+sql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape a string in SQL Server so that it is safe to use in LIKE expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression)

Comment: Figured there was a few duplicates...couldn't remember the term 'escape a string' to search for it for the life of me.

Comment: @Twelfth . . . To the best of my understanding, `'%'` is a wildcard for `like`.  `charindex()` doesn't accept wildcards.  You can see a test here (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/11183).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the percent sign `%`:

```
charindex(field,'[%]') from...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `charindex('%', field) from...` instead