# How to escape @ symbol in SQL WHERE Clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, escaping

I'm trying to run something like this in Excel:

```
SELECT currency_id, period_id, date, price_1, price_2

FROM Prices

WHERE scenario_id='1' AND period_from='04/14/2014' AND period_to='04/14/2014'
 AND date='04/14/2014' AND date_time='04/14/2014' price_type='r@periodic'
```

How to escape @ symbol in SQL WHERE Clause?

I got "Incorrect syntax near 'price_type' error.

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression

Comment: Your query shouldn't give you a syntax error, and if it does, then you have an error in another part of your query. So post the full error message and the full query too

Comment: If the value you are trying to match has an @ symbol, removing it will cause a zero result set anyway.

Comment: Please show us the complete and exact error message

Comment: I'm running this query from Excel. The pop up message I get is 'Incorrect syntax near 'price_type'.

Answer (score 2):

AND operator was missing between date_time='04/14/2014' and price_type='r@periodic'

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Bit VARCHAR(10) = 'r@period'
select REPLACE(@Bit,'@','')
```