# SQL Server incorrect syntax near '-' on subtraction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two MS SQL Server queries that, when run separately, produce the correct results, but when I try to subtract the results from one from the other, I receive the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

Any thoughts? I've counted my parentheses over and over, but I could be totally missing something.

The complete query is:

```
GO
declare @oldDate DATETIME = '3/31/2014';
declare @newDate DATETIME = '5/1/2014';

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM([Revenue]), 0) FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel]
WHERE [Opp_ID] IN (
    -- Select everything in the new date
    SELECT [Opp_ID] FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel]
    WHERE [Stage] = '6. Upside' 
    AND ([Status] = 'Won - Not Booked' OR [Status] = 'Open') AND [Report_Date] = @newDate

    Except
    -- everything in the old date
    (SELECT [Opp_ID] FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel]
    WHERE [Stage] = '6. Upside' 
    AND ([Status] = 'Won - Not Booked' OR [Status] = 'Open') AND [Report_Date] = @oldDate
    Union
    -- everything that was a new item
    SELECT [Opp_ID] FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel]
        WHERE [Opp_ID] NOT IN (SELECT [Opp_ID] FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel]
        WHERE [Report_Date] = @oldDate)
    AND [Stage] = '6. Upside' 
    AND ([Status] = 'Won - Not Booked' OR [Status] = 'Open') AND [Report_Date] = @newDate
    Union
    -- everything that was added to upside (stage change)
    SELECT [t].[Opp_ID]
      FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel][t]
      Join [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel][s] On [t].[Opp_ID] = [s].[Opp_ID]
      WHERE [t].[Report_Date] = @newDate And [t].[Stage] = '6. Upside'
      And ([t].[Status] = 'Open' Or [t].[Status] = 'Won - Not Booked')
      And ([s].[Stage] = '7. Forecast' And [s].[Report_Date] = @oldDate)
    )
) AND [Report_Date] = @newDate)
-
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM([Revenue]), 0) FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel]
WHERE [Opp_ID] IN (
    -- Select everything in the old date
    SELECT [Opp_ID] FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel]
    WHERE [Stage] = '6. Upside' 
    AND ([Status] = 'Won - Not Booked' OR [Status] = 'Open') AND [Report_Date] = @oldDate

    Except
    -- everything that was taken from upside (stage change)
    (-- Select everything in the new date
    SELECT [Opp_ID] FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel]
        WHERE [Stage] = '6. Upside' 
        AND ([Status] = 'Won - Not Booked' OR [Status] = 'Open') AND [Report_Date] = @newDate
    Union
    SELECT [t].[Opp_ID]
      FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel][t]
      Join [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel][s] On [t].[Opp_ID] = [s].[Opp_ID]
      WHERE [t].[Report_Date] = @newDate And [t].[Stage] = '7. Forecast'
      And ([t].[Status] = 'Open' Or [t].[Status] = 'Won - Not Booked')
      And ([s].[Stage] = '6. Upside' And [s].[Report_Date] = @oldDate)
    Union
    -- everything that was booked
    SELECT [s].[Opp_ID]
        FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel][t]
        Join [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel][s] On [t].[Opp_ID] = [s].[Opp_ID]
        WHERE [s].[Stage] = '6. Upside' AND [t].[Report_Date] = @newDate And [t].[Status] = 'Closed - Won'
        And [s].[Report_Date] = @oldDate And [s].[Status] != 'Closed - Won'
    Union
    -- everything that went to proposed
    SELECT [t].[Opp_ID]
      FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel][t]
      Join [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel][s] On [t].[Opp_ID] = [s].[Opp_ID]
      WHERE [t].[Report_Date] = @newDate And [t].[Stage] = '5. Proposed'
      And ([t].[Status] = 'Open' Or [t].[Status] = 'Won - Not Booked')
      And ([s].[Stage] = '6. Upside' And [s].[Report_Date] = @oldDate)
      And ([s].[Status] = 'Open' Or [s].[Status] = 'Won - Not Booked')
    Union
    -- everything that was lost
    SELECT [s].[Opp_ID]
        FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel][t]
        Join [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel][s] On [t].[Opp_ID] = [s].[Opp_ID]
        WHERE [s].[Stage] = '6. Upside' AND [t].[Report_Date] = @newDate And ([t].[Status] = 'Closed - Lost' Or [t].[Status] = 'Inactive')
        And [s].[Report_Date] = @oldDate And ([s].[Status] != 'Closed - Lost' And [s].[Status] != 'Inactive')
    )
) AND [Report_Date] = @oldDate)
```

Comment: You cannot use `-` between two queries.  Either put a `select` in front to subtract two scalars or use `except` for set "subtraction".

Comment: Is the query auto-generated? All those square bracket are useless

Comment: @GordonLinoff was right. I was being an idiot because I had dragged this out of my main procedure and was rewriting it. I wrapped the whole thing like so and it works (not enough rep to answer my own question):`SELECT DISTINCT (query1) - (query2)
FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[cboyd_monthly_finance_funnel];`

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want the result to go?

Into a variable or displayed in console?

Try

```
SELECT (QUERY1) - (QUERY2)
```

for the console
and

```
DECLARE @myvar INTEGER
SELECT @myvar = (QUERY1) - (QUERY2)
```

for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is when you use "Won - Not Booked".. i suggest using escape characters and see how it goes. check 
[Escape a string in SQL Server so that it is safe to use in LIKE expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression) and [Using Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: Every occurrence of that string (that I see) is surrounded by single quotes and hence is a string literal.