# How do I do quotes within quotes in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, quotes, varchar

I have a case statement that will set a varchar variable `@stored_proc_name` to the name of a procedure that I want to call later on. One of the procedures I want to call takes a varchar as an argument (and also an int). How do I do this? Currently what I have is this

```
SELECT @stored_proc_name = CASE @p_process_name
      WHEN 'misdate'               THEN 'findb..sp_cycle_date_daily' 
      WHEN 'balpremmis'            THEN 'findb..pc_bal_writ_prem'
      WHEN 'ursctl'                THEN 'MIS_feeds..pc_mis_update_feed_control "URSPO", 1'
      ELSE NULL
END

EXECUTE @stored_proc_name
```

The last one is my procedure that takes arguments, where "URSPO" should be the first, and 1 is the int.  It is running on SQL server 2k8 (I think I remember some difference with single vs. double quotes between this and older versions).  Is what I have correct? I admit that I haven't tested it yet, but it is a part of a huge process that I really don't want to kick off right now.

Thank for any help!

Comment: If you want to escape a single tick in SQL server, just use a double tick like this: `'MIS_feeds..pc_mis_update_feed_control ''URSPO'', 1'`

Comment: That's right, that sounds familiar. Thank you!

Comment: @entropic, consider posting it as answer and ask OP to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To escape a single quote inside a string literal, use a double quote like below.  See the [Constants section in the BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx) for more information:

```
select ' '' ' -- creates a string containing a space, a single quote, and another space
```

In your example, this would be the string:

```
'MIS_feeds..pc_mis_update_feed_control ''URSPO'', 1'
```

If you were going to use this string in a LIKE expression, you might want to refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression).

And if you were going to build a string to be a SQL identifier, you might want to escape it using the [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
set quoted_identifier off;
Select "'Hi'"
```

quoted_identifiere will enable you to use ", instead of ';