# MSQL: Syntax error near ')' in the full-text search condition

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I using SqlServer Full Text Search. In my website, user can input search term, and I looking for it.

I noticed that several symbols, such as tilda ('~') cause sql server to throw the following error:

```
Syntax error near ')' in the full-text search condition '(~~)
```

What is the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: Do you use String concatenation to build the search query?

Comment: Refer this post to achieve what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression

Answer (score 0):

I did 2 changes. Not sure which one fixed this issue, but now it is fine:

1. I changed CONTAINSTABLE to FREETEXTTABLE
2. I wrapped my search querywith "".

Hope this will help someone.