# If string has special character then how to use substring function

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SUBSTRING('Electronic Payment Successful.;  -- Transaction Id <P291118333151428004>; Card <1272>;  Amt <$118.00>; Date <11/29/2018 3:14:27 PM>; Vendor Name <TSYS>; Status Code<1> ;Status Description <Transaction Approved>; Response Code<00> ;Response Description <Approved>; Approval Code <121041>; Processor TransId <4401919651>;',53,19)
```

Gives me the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax
>   near '%Electronic Payment Successful.; -- Transaction Id
>   ; Card <1272>; Amt ; Date <11/29/2018

Comment: Giving me error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '%Electronic Payment Successful.;  -- Transaction Id <P291118333151428004>; Card <1272>;  Amt <$118.00>; Date <11/29/2018 3:14:27 '.

Comment: I get `P291118333151428004`

Comment: i am getting error message

Comment: In that case it seems you are doing something other than the code you've posted - because that code works.

Comment: There is something else going on in your code. Perhaps you forgot to close the quotes, or there is a single quote embedded in the string?

Comment: For a discussion on how to escape special chars in SQL Server, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression

Comment: Code works as is. Is it part of a string to use for a prepared statement?