# Avoid escaping characters when converting from tabular data to json

Tags: json, t-sql

I have some problems converting tabular data to JSON using the FOR JSON PATH syntax:

If i do a standard query:

```
SELECT b.Name FROM dbo
```

I get results of the form: 12/5-A-1. I need this converted to JSON data without escaping the backslash character. However, when i convert it to JSON:

```
SELECT b.Name FROM dbo FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

the result is of the form: `{"Name": "12\/5-A-1"}`

How can i do this transformation without escaping the backslash character and get the result `{"Name": "12/5-A-1"}`?

Comment: Check if this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/escape-a-string-in-sql-server-so-that-it-is-safe-to-use-in-like-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a common table expression to generate the json, and then simply use `replace` when selecting from the common table expression.

First, create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    [Name] nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T ([Name]) VALUES ('12/5-A-1');
```

The cte:

```
WITH CTE(Escaped) AS
(

    SELECT [Name]
    FROM @T
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
```

The final select:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Escaped, '\/','/') As Result
FROM CTE
```

Result:

```
{"Name":"12/5-A-1"}
```