# Sql where statement with = works but LIKE does not

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sql where statement with = works but LIKE does not
Is there a fix for this?

Here is the exact code:

```
create table zSyn (xField nvarchar(255));
insert into zSyn(xField)
select 'DEVCON 5 Minute Epoxy amber [1:1]';

--Works and returns 1 row:
select * from zSyn
where xField = 'DEVCON 5 Minute Epoxy amber [1:1]';

--Does NOT return any rows:
select * from zSyn
where xField like '%' + 'DEVCON 5 Minute Epoxy amber [1:1]' + '%'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape `[]`:

```
select * from zSyn
where xField like ('%' + 'DEVCON 5 Minute Epoxy amber ![1:1!]' + '%') ESCAPE '!';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d0bd4fc5e1eb962919b8e4fa0d75eb75)**

Comment: Great eye!  I would have looked at that a hundred times, and I would never see that  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti TIL:  [The JDBC syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56923634/5070879) :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the square braces represent character classes in SQL Server `like`.  One method is to use `escape`.  Here are two other options:

```
xField like '%' + 'DEVCON 5 Minute Epoxy amber [[]1:1]' + '%'
xField like '%' + 'DEVCON 5 Minute Epoxy amber _1:1_' + '%'
```

The second will match any character, including a square brace.  That is probably okay for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option if you want to avoid the need to escape the string is to use charindex()

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From  zSyn
 Where charindex('DEVCON 5 Minute Epoxy amber [1:1]',xField)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the square brackets are messing with LIKE because you can sometimes use square brackets for finding numerical or alphabetic characters i.e. LIKE ([A-Z])

```
SELECT * FROM zSyn WHERE xField LIKE ('%DEVCON 5 Minute Epoxy amber %1:1%')
```